# How do I depth-test for a certain range?

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer, depth-testing

What is the most common/simplest/fastest way to depth-test for a certain range?

`pass if (currentDepth-offset < newDepth && newDepth < currentDepth)`

- currentDepth := value in the depth buffer
- offset := constant (know at compile-time and for all fragments the same)
- newDepth := depth of the fragment

Ideally, the function glDepthFunc(...) would be more flexible.

Comment: Are you asking about desktop OpenGL or OpenGL ES? They're not the same, you know.

Comment: I'm using OpenGL 4.2. That being said, I follow the OpenGL ES 2.0 way of doing things. So to answer your question: It would be great, if it could be done with OpenGL ES 2.0, but if there is an easier/faster way in OpenGL 4.2, I'll gladly adjust my coding style.

Comment: Is "currentDepth-offset" a constant value? Is it some constant + the depth (in window space), is it a constant+depth in camera/eye space, or is it some arbitrary value?

Comment: "currentDepth-offset" is not constant. I'm having the "constant + the depth (in window space)" case.

Answer (score 0):

Is [glPolygonOffset](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPolygonOffset.xml) what you're looking for? (Depending on what you want with that offset, of course).